# How to install a Trust webcam "Exis" if it does not get detected on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, webcam, trust

After plugging in a Trust "Exis" webcam, it could not be detected. I checked other USB ports, and the alert of not being detected did not pop up anymore. On the net, I found [Windows 10 not detecting my Trust webcam](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/windows-10-not-detecting-my-trust-webcam.3452067/) which shows that I am not the first with this.

How to install a Trust Webcam Exis if it does not get detected on Windows 10?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Restart your computer with the camera plugged in, and it will be detected.

After the restart, the Windows Camera app worked, but after a short while only, I ran into a black screen in the Windows Camera app. I then had to restart again, and everything has worked since then.

See also "IT Crowd": [Hello, IT. Have you tried turning it off and on again?](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/The_IT_Crowd)

Comment: Who downvotes should tell why. I do not see anything wrong. I only forgot to restart the computer, which cost me some time, so why the downvotes? If it is too silly to be worth mentioning, I guess that some people might be silly enough as well.